# Replacing Text link as link with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I seem to be having an issue replacing a text link with a link to the site posted, it isn't linking.

The code:

```
$status_text = preg_replace('#(\A|[^=\]\'"a-zA-Z0-9])(http[s]?://(.+?)/[^()<>\s]+)#i', '\\1<a href="\\2">\\3</a>', $status_text);
echo $status_text;
```

`$status_text` is pulled from a MySQL field named `contents`, and contains other text, but i'd just like to linkify the link. *Additionally*, i'd also like it to not display the full URL, just the main domain.

UPDATE: We have two other preg_replaces on the same page, looking for things with + and # in front of them that link to areas of the site, they currently work and need to not conflict with the above:

```
$status_text = preg_replace("/#([a-z_0-9]+)/i", "<a href=\"http://url.com/hashlink/$1\">$0</a>", $status_text);


$status_text = preg_replace("/\+([a-z_0-9]+)/i", "<a href=\"http://url.com/pluslink/$1\">$0</a>", $status_text);
```

Comment: could you give an example of the text you are working with?

Comment: @mason81 Sure, its a simple text line, e.g:

hello http:// hello . com (spaces to avoid the autolink here)

Comment: When you say you want to "not display the full URL, just the main domain" are you referring to the href for the link or the label for the link?

Comment: @mason81 it would be the label for the link, e.g blah . com / blah . html, would just show blah . com

Comment: This has been asked before - Search: "Linkify URL". Bottom line: doing this correctly is not easy. See: [The Problem with URLs](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/the-problem-with-urls.html).

Comment: @mobile - You can avoid autolinking by putting a URL in backquotes, like this: `http://example.com/`. Also, you've put a lot of important detail about your question into comments.  You should [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13105960/edit) and put everything relevant there, so that new people trying to answer can get the whole question in one place, from your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here, try this:

```
$status_text = preg_replace('|([\w\d]*)\s?(https?://([\d\w\.-]+\.[\w\.]{2,6})[^\s\]\[\<\>]*/?)|i', '$1 <a href="$2">$3</a>', $status_text);
echo $status_text;
```

or to make it a little easer to read:

```
$m = '|([\w\d]*)\s?(https?://([\d\w\.-]+\.[\w\.]{2,6})[^\s\]\[\<\>]*/?)|i';
$r = '$1 <a href="$2">$3</a>';

$status_text = preg_replace($m,$r,$status_text);
echo $status_text;
```

**EDIT** -- Updating due to new info in the OP --

Your hashtag regex does not take into account hashes in URLs, so let's fix that...
Also, you should match for URLs before matching for hash-tags or plus-tags because otherwise you will mess up the links you create for the hash-tags and plus-tags

```
$status_text = preg_replace('|(https?://([\d\w\.-]+\.[\w\.]{2,6})[^\s\]\[\<\>]*/?)|i', '<a href="$1">$2</a>', $status_text);
$status_text = preg_replace('|\B#([\d\w_]+)|i', '<a href="http://url.com/pluslink/$1">$0</a>', $status_text);
$status_text = preg_replace('|\B\+([\d\w_]+)|i', '<a href="http://url.com/pluslink/$1">$0</a>', $status_text);
```

Or to make it a little easier to read...

```
$match_href = '|(https?://([\d\w\.-]+\.[\w\.]{2,6})[^\s\]\[\<\>]*/?)|i';
$match_hash = '|\B#([\d\w_]+)|i';
$match_plus = '|\B\+([\d\w_]+)|i';
$replace_url = '<a href="$1">$2</a>';
$replace_tag = '<a href="http://url.com/pluslink/$1">$0</a>';

$status_text = preg_replace($match_href, $replace_url, $status_text);
$status_text = preg_replace($match_hash, $replace_tag, $status_text);
$status_text = preg_replace($match_plus, $replace_tag, $status_text);
```

**EDIT AGAIN** -- Adding a URL that might be helpful --

You can test out regular expressions here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

**ANOTHER EDIT**

As per a comment/question, if you want to account for urls that lack the http protocol, use the following:

```
$status_text = preg_replace('|((https?://)?([\d\w\.-]+\.[\w\.]{2,6})[^\s\]\[\<\>]*/?)|i', '<a href="$1">$3</a>', $status_text);
$status_text = preg_replace('|\B#([\d\w_]+)|i', '<a href="http://url.com/pluslink/$1">$0</a>', $status_text);
$status_text = preg_replace('|\B\+([\d\w_]+)|i', '<a href="http://url.com/pluslink/$1">$0</a>', $status_text);
```

Or to make it a little easier to read...

```
$match_href = '|((https?://)?([\d\w\.-]+\.[\w\.]{2,6})[^\s\]\[\<\>]*/?)|i';
$match_hash = '|\B#([\d\w_]+)|i';
$match_plus = '|\B\+([\d\w_]+)|i';
$replace_url = '<a href="$1">$3</a>';
$replace_tag = '<a href="http://url.com/pluslink/$1">$0</a>';

$status_text = preg_replace($match_href, $replace_url, $status_text);
$status_text = preg_replace($match_hash, $replace_tag, $status_text);
$status_text = preg_replace($match_plus, $replace_tag, $status_text);
```

**EXAMPLE USAGE**

Input: (Text from DB -> $status_text)

```
<!-- language-all: lang-none -->
Hi, this is an example. This is a url http://stackoverflow.com/ 
and this is a hash reference that we want to link to an internal 
post #AwesomePost123 and this one is a plus reference we want to 
link to an internal post +AwesomePost123 and finally an example 
of a url without the http protocol www.stackoverflow.com
```

Output: (After running through the regex)

```
<!-- language-all: lang-none -->
Hi, this is an example. This is a url <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">stackoverflow.com</a> 
and this is a hash reference that we want to link to an internal 
post <a href="http://url.com/pluslink/AwesomePost123">#AwesomePost123</a> and this one is a plus reference we want to 
link to an internal post <a href="http://url.com/pluslink/AwesomePost123">+AwesomePost123</a> and finally an example 
of a url without the http protocol <a href="www.stackoverflow.com">www.stackoverflow.com</a>
```

Comment: I tried it with hello http:// hello . com, and it links, but doesn't have a space before the http

I'm also using 2 other preg_replaces for other things such as #hashtags, and it looks like it's taken out the a href for those

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "it doesn't have a space before the http", could you clarify?

Comment: Could you post the code for your other preg_replaces with a full example (including the hashtags you mention) in the order that it processes? That would help me help you better.

Comment: Regarding that space... I edited my answer to include a space between the text and the link as that would seem to make the most sense. I meant to include it before, but apparently missed it.

Comment: I've updated the original link with the other preg_replaces, thanks!

Comment: Thank you. Example text would still be helpful, but I updated my answer to reflect your other preg_replaces...

Comment: Your first code works perfectly, thanks, your second one doesn't take into account the hashlink URL

Comment: well, without example text, it is difficult to recreate what you are getting. Did you parse for full URLs first before parsing for hash tags and plus tags? If you don't run the URL test first, you're going to double replace the hash and plus tag urls...

Comment: I have a slight issue with it not replacing the first word in the text line now. Its hard to say but the whole text line needs to be examined for +words #words and http:// links

Comment: What do you mean "not replacing the first word in the text line"? What do you want to replace it with?

Comment: for example, the text: #hello this is a line of text, doesn't replace the #hello

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Sorry, I made the mistake of assuming hash tags would only occur after a white-space... I replaced it with \B which matches anything that is not a word-boundary. That should fix it...

Comment: Hmm, that seemed to linkify the whole sentence, e.g #hello hello, caused the whole sentence to be linked

Comment: odd... Maybe it's because I forgot the closing </a> on the 2nd replace string? fixed

Comment: What's the point of the whole "http://url.com/pluslink" portion, could someone please explain? Also, this does not work for www.somesite.com links, could you update it to accommodate those as well?

Comment: @danL -- the `url.com/pluslink` is the url example provided by the OP (along with `url.com/hashlink`) and is significant only in that it is a placeholder and could just as easily have been `example.com/subdir/` or otherwise.

Comment: @danL -- also, it will work with `www.somesite.com` links provided they are prefixed with `http://` or `https://`. I'll update the answer to include a different regex for making http(s) optional...

Comment: @danL -- updated to include example usage and also make http protocol part of the match optional.

Comment: Thank you very much it makes sense now.

Comment: Thank you sir! You're the great master!

Answer (score 0):

Can you just try this:

```
function makeClickableLinks($s) {
  return preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $s);
}
```

To test it, try this:

```
echo makeClickableLinks('Hello world, you go to www.google.com to check! also http://www.google.com/ works too!');
```

Demo here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/hkOdCM

Comment: I've updated my original post with 2 other preg_replaces we have that it would need to not conflict with, trying this now, thanks

Edit: It causes the hashlinks to echo this: http://url.com/hashlink/">#blah