# PHP - preg_replace - text link as clickable link

Tags: php

I use this preg_replace to change text urls to clickable in my script: [Replacing Text link as link with preg_replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105960/replacing-text-link-as-link-with-preg-replace)

yesterday I tested my script and these preg_replace doesn't work fine.

Here is example:

```
(...) stronie  http://tpn.pl/nowosci/uwaga-skiturowcy-1).
```

And these preg_replace finally create this:

```
stronie <a href="http://tpn.pl/nowosci/uwaga-skiturowcy-1)." target="_blank">tpn.pl</a>
```

Why this preg_replace added ")." at the end of an URL? How to accept only "A-Z, a-z, 0-9, /" at the end of an URL string (I think I wrote everything accept ends of url ?)?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here is my code:

```
$sub_message = preg_replace('|([\w\d]*)\s?(https?://([\d\w\.-]+\.[\w\.]{2,6})[^\s\]\[\<\>]*/?)|i', '$1 <a target="_blank" href="$2">$3</a>', $value['description']);
$sub_message = trim(str_replace("\n", "<br />", $sub_message));
```

Comment: Post your code, we don't want to guess it.

Comment: I added my code, sorry, I forgot.

Comment: Take a look at this https://regex101.com/r/mS9dT2/1 I added a capturing group, now you can see why you also get ").".

Comment: This regex also get **).** at the end of an URL string.

Comment: I know, now take a close look at the link and you'll see why.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand why it doesn't work fine... Can you tell me where is a problem ?

Comment: This part `[^\s\]\[\<\>]*` matches **any** character which **isn't** present in the list, that means anything else than `\r \n \t \f ] [ < >` gets captured.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105595/discussion-between-majkson-and-charlotte-dunois).

Comment: OK, I replaced this part for: ([^A-Za-z0-9\/\-\.]*) but now it get only this: "http://tpn.pl/" - why?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to change urls to links in a string :

```
<?php

$x="foobar http://example.com foobar";
echo preg_replace("~(https?://(?:www\.)?[^\s]+)~i","<a href='$1'>$1</a>",$x);
```

> Online demo : https://eval.in/532195

Comment: AS text, I wolud like to have only domain name so it should get as result: `foobar <a href="http://example.com">example.com</a> foobar`